# How do I set a dropdown option by value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a fiddle that has some slight demo code: http://jsfiddle.net/mwoods98/MHrJJ/

I have a request that is being sent via ajax and it's returning some values via JSON. 
With that, I'm taking what is returned and filling in a form. I'm filling in the form
with the other values but I can't quite figure out how to set the dropdown to a value that is returned.

```
$('#PosTitle').find('option:eq(PosVar)').val().prop('selected', true);
```

I have tired this and it doesn't work. PosVar is a variable that I'm setting to a number that is returned from ajax.

UPDATE: Thanks for both of the answers, I have discovered something.

I'm using this code to make the drop downs look better but also I need a drop down that can have multimple lines of HTML.

http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

When I remove this js, the form fills in.

I'm open to using another library that gives me the ability to use multiple rows in a select dropdown and pass HTML to it.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
var PosVar = 9;
$('#PosTitle').val(PosVar);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MHrJJ/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `.val()`

```
$('#PosTitle').find('option:eq(PosVar)').prop('selected', true);
```

`.val()` will not return `this` object .. So you cannot chain it further..

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MHrJJ/6/)**